# NRPE Issue Unable to Read output Check_Access_Log

Tags: sudo, nagios, nrpe

In NRPE running xinetd I am able to run the script locally, but NRPE reports unable to read output when trying to run it remotely.  Any suggestions?:

```
    [root@travel log]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -t 30 -c check_access_log -a -l /var/log/httpd/vhosts/xxxxxx/access_log
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

If I run the script directly on the client:

```
    ./check_access_log.pl -l /var/log/httpd/vhosts/xxxxxxx/access_log
ACCESS_STATUS OK - FAILURE_RATE 0 | Total=0;; FAIL=0%;10;20 BytesServed=0kB;; 20X=0;; 30X=0;; 403=0;; 404=0;; 40X=0;; 500=0;; 503=0;; 50X=0;; no_status=0;; Other=0;;
```

If I run a check NRPE:

```
[root@travel log]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -t 30 -
NRPE v2.14
```

Now I am running my NRPE using Xinetd.d:

```
# default: on
# description: NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Executor)
service nrpe
{
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream
        port            = 5666
        wait            = no
        user            = nagios
        group           = nagios
        server          = /usr/local/nagios/bin/nrpe
        server_args     = -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg --inetd
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         = no
        only_from       = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
}
```

Here is my nrpe.cfg file.

```
#############################################################################
# Sample NRPE Config File 
# Written by: Ethan Galstad (nagios@nagios.org)
# 
# Last Modified: 11-23-2007
#
# NOTES:
# This is a sample configuration file for the NRPE daemon.  It needs to be
# located on the remote host that is running the NRPE daemon, not the host
# from which the check_nrpe client is being executed.
#############################################################################


# LOG FACILITY
# The syslog facility that should be used for logging purposes.

log_facility=daemon



# PID FILE
# The name of the file in which the NRPE daemon should write it's process ID
# number.  The file is only written if the NRPE daemon is started by the root
# user and is running in standalone mode.

pid_file=/var/run/nrpe.pid



# PORT NUMBER
# Port number we should wait for connections on.
# NOTE: This must be a non-priviledged port (i.e. > 1024).
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

server_port=5666



# SERVER ADDRESS
# Address that nrpe should bind to in case there are more than one interface
# and you do not want nrpe to bind on all interfaces.
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

#server_address=127.0.0.1



# NRPE USER
# This determines the effective user that the NRPE daemon should run as.  
# You can either supply a username or a UID.
# 
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

nrpe_user=nagios



# NRPE GROUP
# This determines the effective group that the NRPE daemon should run as.  
# You can either supply a group name or a GID.
# 
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

nrpe_group=nagios



# ALLOWED HOST ADDRESSES
# This is an optional comma-delimited list of IP address or hostnames 
# that are allowed to talk to the NRPE daemon.
#
# Note: The daemon only does rudimentary checking of the client's IP
# address.  I would highly recommend adding entries in your /etc/hosts.allow
# file to allow only the specified host to connect to the port
# you are running this daemon on.
#
# NOTE: This option is ignored if NRPE is running under either inetd or xinetd

allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1



# COMMAND ARGUMENT PROCESSING
# This option determines whether or not the NRPE daemon will allow clients
# to specify arguments to commands that are executed.  This option only works
# if the daemon was configured with the --enable-command-args configure script
# option.  
#
# *** ENABLING THIS OPTION IS A SECURITY RISK! *** 
# Read the SECURITY file for information on some of the security implications
# of enabling this variable.
#
# Values: 0=do not allow arguments, 1=allow command arguments

dont_blame_nrpe=1



# COMMAND PREFIX
# This option allows you to prefix all commands with a user-defined string.
# A space is automatically added between the specified prefix string and the
# command line from the command definition.
#
# *** THIS EXAMPLE MAY POSE A POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK, SO USE WITH CAUTION! ***
# Usage scenario: 
# Execute restricted commmands using sudo.  For this to work, you need to add
# the nagios user to your /etc/sudoers.  An example entry for alllowing 
# execution of the plugins from might be:
#
# nagios          ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
#
# This lets the nagios user run all commands in that directory (and only them)
# without asking for a password.  If you do this, make sure you don't give
# random users write access to that directory or its contents!

 command_prefix=/usr/bin/sudo 



# DEBUGGING OPTION
# This option determines whether or not debugging messages are logged to the
# syslog facility.
# Values: 0=debugging off, 1=debugging on

debug=0



# COMMAND TIMEOUT
# This specifies the maximum number of seconds that the NRPE daemon will
# allow plugins to finish executing before killing them off.

command_timeout=60



# CONNECTION TIMEOUT
# This specifies the maximum number of seconds that the NRPE daemon will
# wait for a connection to be established before exiting. This is sometimes
# seen where a network problem stops the SSL being established even though
# all network sessions are connected. This causes the nrpe daemons to
# accumulate, eating system resources. Do not set this too low.

connection_timeout=300



# WEEK RANDOM SEED OPTION
# This directive allows you to use SSL even if your system does not have
# a /dev/random or /dev/urandom (on purpose or because the necessary patches
# were not applied). The random number generator will be seeded from a file
# which is either a file pointed to by the environment valiable $RANDFILE
# or $HOME/.rnd. If neither exists, the pseudo random number generator will
# be initialized and a warning will be issued.
# Values: 0=only seed from /dev/[u]random, 1=also seed from weak randomness

#allow_weak_random_seed=1



# INCLUDE CONFIG FILE
# This directive allows you to include definitions from an external config file.

#include=<somefile.cfg>



# INCLUDE CONFIG DIRECTORY
# This directive allows you to include definitions from config files (with a
# .cfg extension) in one or more directories (with recursion).

#include_dir=<somedirectory>
include_dir=/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe



# COMMAND DEFINITIONS
# Command definitions that this daemon will run.  Definitions
# are in the following format:
#
# command[<command_name>]=<command_line>
#
# When the daemon receives a request to return the results of <command_name>
# it will execute the command specified by the <command_line> argument.
#
# Unlike Nagios, the command line cannot contain macros - it must be
# typed exactly as it should be executed.
#
# Note: Any plugins that are used in the command lines must reside
# on the machine that this daemon is running on!  The examples below
# assume that you have plugins installed in a /usr/local/nagios/libexec
# directory.  Also note that you will have to modify the definitions below
# to match the argument format the plugins expect.  Remember, these are
# examples only!


# The following examples use hardcoded command arguments...
#command[check_access_log]=/usr/local/libexec/check_access_log.pl -l $ARG1$ -a
#command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 5 -c 10
#command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
#command[check_hda1]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/hda1
#command[check_zombie_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 5 -c 10 -s Z
#command[check_total_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 150 -c 200 


# The following examples allow user-supplied arguments and can
# only be used if the NRPE daemon was compiled with support for 
# command arguments *AND* the dont_blame_nrpe directive in this
# config file is set to '1'.  This poses a potential security risk, so
# make sure you read the SECURITY file before doing this.

command[check_access_log]=/usr/local/libexec/check_access_log.pl
#command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
#command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
#command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
#command[check_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -s $ARG3$
```

And my sudoers file:

```
## Sudoers allows particular users to run various commands as
## the root user, without needing the root password.
##
## Examples are provided at the bottom of the file for collections
## of related commands, which can then be delegated out to particular
## users or groups.
## 
## This file must be edited with the 'visudo' command.

## Host Aliases
## Groups of machines. You may prefer to use hostnames (perhaps using 
## wildcards for entire domains) or IP addresses instead.
# Host_Alias     FILESERVERS = fs1, fs2
# Host_Alias     MAILSERVERS = smtp, smtp2

## User Aliases
## These aren't often necessary, as you can use regular groups
## (ie, from files, LDAP, NIS, etc) in this file - just use %groupname 
## rather than USERALIAS
# User_Alias ADMINS = jsmith, mikem


## Command Aliases
## These are groups of related commands...

## Networking
# Cmnd_Alias NETWORKING = /sbin/route, /sbin/ifconfig, /bin/ping, /sbin/dhclient, /usr/bin/net, /sbin/iptables, /usr/bin/rfcomm, /usr/bin/wvdial, /sbin/iwconfig, /sbin/mii-tool

## Installation and management of software
# Cmnd_Alias SOFTWARE = /bin/rpm, /usr/bin/up2date, /usr/bin/yum

## Services
# Cmnd_Alias SERVICES = /sbin/service, /sbin/chkconfig

## Updating the locate database
# Cmnd_Alias LOCATE = /usr/bin/updatedb

## Storage
# Cmnd_Alias STORAGE = /sbin/fdisk, /sbin/sfdisk, /sbin/parted, /sbin/partprobe, /bin/mount, /bin/umount

## Delegating permissions
# Cmnd_Alias DELEGATING = /usr/sbin/visudo, /bin/chown, /bin/chmod, /bin/chgrp 

## Processes
# Cmnd_Alias PROCESSES = /bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/kill, /usr/bin/killall

## Drivers
# Cmnd_Alias DRIVERS = /sbin/modprobe

# Defaults specification

#
# Disable "ssh hostname sudo <cmd>", because it will show the password in clear. 
#         You have to run "ssh -t hostname sudo <cmd>".
#
# Defaults    requiretty

#
# Refuse to run if unable to disable echo on the tty. This setting should also be
# changed in order to be able to use sudo without a tty. See requiretty above.
#
Defaults   !visiblepw

#
# Preserving HOME has security implications since many programs
# use it when searching for configuration files. Note that HOME
# is already set when the the env_reset option is enabled, so
# this option is only effective for configurations where either
# env_reset is disabled or HOME is present in the env_keep list.
#
Defaults    always_set_home

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

#
# Adding HOME to env_keep may enable a user to run unrestricted
# commands via sudo.
#
# Defaults   env_keep += "HOME"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## Next comes the main part: which users can run what software on 
## which machines (the sudoers file can be shared between multiple
## systems).
## Syntax:
##
##  user    MACHINE=COMMANDS
##
## The COMMANDS section may have other options added to it.
##
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software, 
## service management apps and more.
# %sys ALL = NETWORKING, SOFTWARE, SERVICES, STORAGE, DELEGATING, PROCESSES, LOCATE, DRIVERS

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
user1       ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
user2           ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL   
user3           ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
nagios      ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL

## Allows members of the users group to mount and unmount the 
## cdrom as root
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /mnt/cdrom, /sbin/umount /mnt/cdrom

## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# NEEDED TO ALLOW NAGIOS TO CHECK SERVICE STATUS
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_init_service

# ASTERISK-SPECIFIC CHECKS
# NOTE: You can uncomment the following line if you are monitoring Asterisk locally
#nagios ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_asterisk_sip_peers.sh, /usr/local/nagios/libexec/nagisk.pl, /usr/sbin/asterisk


# NEEDED TO ALLOW NAGIOS TO CHECK SERVICE STATUS
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_init_service

# ASTERISK-SPECIFIC CHECKS
# NOTE: You can uncomment the following line if you are monitoring Asterisk locally
#nagios ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_asterisk_sip_peers.sh, /usr/local/nagios/libexec/nagisk.pl, /usr/sbin/asterisk
```

Comment: When you run it locally, are you running it as user nagios? (I've been chasing missing privileges once or twice.)

Comment: No, I run it as Sudo or root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.  The devil was in the details:

```
command[check_access_log]=/usr/local/libexec/check_access_log.pl
```

Needed to be:

```
command[check_access_log]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_access_log.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test-run it as the same user that NRPE is running as ("nagios", according to your xinetd conf).

If you **have** to run this plugin as root, then you'll need to set up sudo so that nagios can run that plugin without a password, as you've done with the other plugins. (Be sure to allow it to run without "requiretty" as well, if applicable.)

(Also, I'm not sure why you have individual nagios commands in sudoers, but also a catch-all ALL/NOPASSWD entry for nagios. This seems dangerous.)

After you confirm that nagios can run that plugin via sudo without a password, you'll want to add sudo to your command[check_access_log] line.